# Visual Studio Code: Is it possible to make a decorations hoverMessage clickable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hi I am developing an extension for VSCode. I am decorating the text editor and hovering some items. Is it possible to make clickable items at `hoverMessage` and modify the range according to it.

The extension is at:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=serayuzgur.crates

You can see the `hoverMessage` from the GIF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using markdown you can then create [a command link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris) that will execute a command when a user clicks on it:

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

const myContent = new vscode.MarkdownString('[link](command:myCommand?arg1)');

// Command Uris are disabled by default for security reasons.
// If you set this flag, make sure your content is not constructed
// using untrusted/unsanitized text.
myContent.isTrusted = true;

const myHover = new Hover(myContent);
```

This command can perform whatever action you want