# VS Code Extension: Click event on decoration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to register a click event on decorations?

I am rendering an icon on the gutter like this. Is there a way to get click event on what is being rendered on the gutter?

```js
const decoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    gutterIconPath: vscode.Uri.file('path/to/icon.svg'),
});

const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

editor.setDecorations(decoration, [new vscode.Range(
    new vscode.Position(1, 0),
    new vscode.Position(1, 0)
)]);
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to handle clicks on the gutter icon directly, but you can have clickable links in the hover message of a decoration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221763/visual-studio-code-is-it-possible-to-make-a-decorations-hovermessage-clickable -

Answer (score 2):

VSCode has the capability but does not offer a API for click events on gutter decorations currently. If you would like such an API vote up https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5455

Answer (score 1):

The latest VSCode version allows to add right clicks for line numbers.

It's not exactly what you asked but unfortunately left clicks aren't supported.

```json
"editor/lineNumber/context": [
  {
     "command": "extension.command",
     "title": "Run fancy command",
     "group": "navigation"
   }
]
```

`editor/lineNumber/context` is only a proposal and not document on https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands